# Optimizing this query that contains multiple subqueries

Tags: mysql, sql

I am having a hard time working this one out in my head and need some help to figure out if there is a better way to produce the same results.

We have 3 tables: stores, departments, sales.
Each store can have many departments.
Each department can have many sales.

I have a query that lists each store and counts & sum's the sales relevant. But the operation is conducted with 2 subqueries when I feel like it should be able to be done in 1.

This is just a sample that runs pretty quickly. In my real world report that I am building I am finding that each subsequent subquery I add significantly reduces the overall performance of the report.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d82b123/1)

```
SELECT `name`,

@totalvalue := ( SELECT SUM(`price`) FROM `sales` WHERE `sales`.`department` IN (
  SELECT `id` FROM `departments` WHERE `departments`.`store`=`stores`.`id`
) ) AS `totalvalue`,

@totalsales := ( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `sales` WHERE `sales`.`department` IN (
  SELECT `id` FROM `departments` WHERE `departments`.`store`=`stores`.`id`
) ) AS `totalsales`,

ROUND(@totalvalue / @totalsales,2) AS `averagesale`

FROM `stores`;
```

How can I produce `totalsales` and `totalvalue` in the 1 subquery, or via a join?

Many thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: The data for `totalvalue` and `totalsales` are same, you can do that with `join`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use GROUP BY aggregation functions and JOIN tables together:

```
SELECT st.name, SUM(s.price) totalvalue, COUNT(s.id) totalsales, ROUND(AVG(s.price),2) averagesale
FROM stores st
LEFT JOIN departments d ON d.store=st.id
LEFT JOIN sales s ON s.department=d.id
GROUP BY st.name
```

LEFT JOIN because you want to show all stores no matter if there is any data or not, otherwise you would use INNER JOIN.

Additionally you do not have to calculate average on your own - its built in function. As long as you do not need to have weighted average this is enough.

Comment: Thanks for your response Rafal. I was missing the GROUP BY on my JOIN tests and as such the query was only returning one result. I knew it was something silly.